# Pertinent versus relevant- what's the usage difference

Tags: word-choice, differences, synonyms, antonyms

> According to various dictionaries, relevant  means having a bearing
>    on the matter at hand. 
>     Pertinent  means “relevant to the matter at hand.
>   Similarly, [**impertinent can be irrelevant.**](https://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en-IN&source=hp&q=impertinent%20meaning&gbv=2&oq=impertinent&gs_l=heirloom-hp.3.1.0l10.401508.403399.0.405414.11.8.0.1.1.0.374.874.2-2j1.3.0....0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-hp..7.4.890.3_GUDBzE6S4)

What, if any, is the difference?

Comment: Where did the quote come from and what research have you already done?

Comment: Although the definitions seem similar and many thesauruses interchange these words, their usage is confusing.

Comment: This question already has an answer here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8223/is-there-a-semantic-difference-between-relevance-and-pertinence

Comment: Well, "impertinent" has a meaning that is quite different from "irrelevant", when used to characterize a person.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The words *relevant* and *pertinent* are members of a group of words that—according to *Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1942)—also includes *germane*, *material*, *apposite*, *applicable*, and *apropos of*.  That dictionary distinguishes between the two words you're interested in as follows:

> That is **relevant** which has any traceable connection, especially logical connection, with the thing under consideration and which has significance in any degree for those who are engaged in such consideration [examples omitted]. ... That is **pertinent** which is so decisively or significantly relevant that it touches the real point at issue or contributes materially to the understanding of what is under discussion or to the solution of that which is in question. [Examples omitted.]

I was surprised at the claim that *pertinent* indicates a stronger degree of relevance than the unadorned word *relevant* does, since I have always imagined that the two words were used for the most part interchangeably, though perhaps with *pertinent* more closely bound to "questions," and *relevant* to "issues." But when I checked the synonym discussion under *relevant* in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003), I found that the same distinctions that MW made in 1942 were on offer (albeit in shortened form) sixty years later:

> RELEVANT implies a traceable, significant, logical connection {found material *relevant* to her case}. ... PERTINENT stresses a clear and decisive relevance {a *pertinent* observation}.

So that's the steadfast view of Merriam-Webster. I remain skeptical about the level of real-world adherence to these distinctions in popular usage today.

Comment: Anecdotally, my own internal lexicon agrees with M-W. While I was waiting for this indeterminably slow Zanzibari connection to load the page, I considered the matter in my head, and my conclusion was the same: relevance is anything related to the topic at hand, while pertinence goes to its crux.